# boost:serialization reconstruction (loading)

Tags: c++, boost-serialization

I'm using boost:serialization to save data structures into a file. The actual data is a pointer vector of classes and subclasses.
However the constructor of the class which is serialized takes as parameter another instantiated class Agent which is an object that controls communication with a simulation API (webots).
I see that in boost::serialization examples, the serializable objects need an empty constructor class() {}; to be used for the reconstruction. However this is impractical in my case. How can I use reconstruction but include the object which communicates with the API ?
One of the serializable classes has this constructor:

```
State(Agent &A, ACTION_MODE const& m);
```

and I've seen from examples in boost docs that I need something like this:

```
State() {};
```

Yet Agent &A must be passed as parameter.
Should I find a way around this (using an extern, a singleton, a global object) or is there a way to modify this behavior when reconstructing ? I'm sure I'm missing something here.

Thank you

EDIT:
Maybe I didn't explain this clearly enough. I get an error message when trying to "load" by reconstructing the serialized data.

```
error: no matching function to call State::State()
```

Which is what made me look into boost::serialize code, and think that it is calling a constructor or copy operator.
How do I make it use a specific constructor to serialize the data and take as an argument the Agent reference &a ?

EDIT#2:

```
template <class S, class P, class A> void Task<S,P,A>::save(const char* file)
{
  std::ofstream ofs(file);
  assert(ofs.good());
  boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
  oa << states;
  ofs.close();
}

template <class S, class P, class A> void Task<S,P,A>::load(const char* file)
{
  std::ifstream ifs(file);
  boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
  ia >> states;
  ifs.close();
}
```

States is friend to boost::serialization::access and has a function serialize.
Saving works fine, loading is the problem.
states is: `boost::ptr_vector<S> states;` where S is a type of State polymorphic class.

State is the base class and has "serialize"

```
template <class Archive>
void State::serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
{
  ar & accel.Xaxis & accel.Yaxis & accel.Zaxis;
  ar & gyro.Xaxis & gyro.Yaxis & gyro.Zaxis;
  ar & gps.Yaxis;
  ar & positions;
  ar & reward & value & hash_value;
}
```

guState inherits from State.

```
template <class Archive>
void guState::serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
{
  ar & boost::serialization::base_object<State>(*this);
  ar & accel.Xaxis & accel.Yaxis & accel.Zaxis;
  ar & gyro.Xaxis & gyro.Yaxis & gyro.Zaxis;
  ar & gps.Yaxis;
  ar & positions;
  ar & reward & value & hash_value;
}
```

accel, gyro, gps are simple structures with 3 double variables. They get serialized above^^.
Positions is an `std::map<std::string,float> positions;`

Looking at the serialized text file, everything appears Ok.
I cannot understand why it calls a constructor when trying to load the file.

EDIT#3:

Base Constructor is:

```
State(Agent &A, ACTION_MODE const& m);
```

Derived Constuctor is:

```
guState::guState(Agent& A, ACTION_MODE const& m) : 
State(A, m)
{
...
}
```

Agent reference &A, kept in each State (or derived State) refers to an object obtained from the simulation API. It controls a robot. I cannot serialize it, and it doesn't make sense serializing it.

When I use:

```
namespace boost { namespace serialization {
  template <class Archive>
    void save_construct_data(Archive & ar,const guState* d,const unsigned int file_version)
    {
      ar << guState::caller;
      ar << guState::mode;
    }
   template <class Archive>
   void load_construct_data(Archive & ar, guState* d,const unsigned int file_version)
   {
      Agent &a;
      ACTION_MODE &m;
      ar >> a;
      ar >> m;
      ::new(d) guState(a,m);
   }
  }
}
```

I get the following errors:

```
invalid use of non-static data member State::caller
invalid use of non-static data member State::mode
```

referring to the references used from the constructor.
And:

```
error: 'a' declared as reference but not initialized
error: 'm' declared as reference but not initialized
```

As you can see, it makes no sense to try and save the reference to Agent, because that reference (even if it could be saved or serialized) will probably be different every time the application is started.

And in loading the construct data, apart from me probably using the wrong syntax, it makes no sense to construct from a serialized reference to agent.

What I belive i need, is a way to tell the load_construct_data how to obtain a reference to an Agent (after initializing an agent object) and use that reference to construct the data.

Does that make any sense ? Do you think this is doable ?

EDIT#4

```
namespace boost { namespace serialization {
  template <class Archive>
    void save_construct_data(Archive & ar,const guState* d,const unsigned int file_version)
    {
      ar <<  guState::caller;
    }
   template <class Archive>
   void load_construct_data(Archive & ar, guState* d,const unsigned int file_version)
   {
      Agent * a;
      ACTION_MODE mode = RAND_SING;
      ar >> a;
      ::new(d) guState(*a,mode);
   }
  }
}
```

It will not allow to serialize guState::caller

I have also made class Agent serializable, and overloaded the load_construct_data and save_construct_data of Agent in order to request from the simulation app a new instance of Agent to control the API.

Comment: Can you post your `load` function that produces the error.

Comment: Can you also post the serialize function, of both the states class and the base class.

Comment: Also, can you add a comment to my answer when you do this so that I know you have done it.

Comment: @Tom I've added the code you asked for. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Tom thank you so much for taking the time to help me out. Your example works, and I see I have missed the save_construct_data and load_construct_data function. It is indeed from where the error was originating. However I am afraid my issue is a bit more compilcated. You see, in order to construct the data, I need to use a reference of an instantiated class which controls the API. I have updated my question to show you what I mean. Sadly I still cannot get this to work. To make matters even worse, I cannot serialize this reference object, because it makes no sense serializing it.

Comment: your load syntax is indeed wrong (you need to load a pointer and reinitilize with that - see the *References* section of the reference section of the documentation.  This will reconstruct the data as you left it. The memory won't be shared with the original source of the reference (how could it be, you could have turned the computer off between saving and loading) but at least your class is back up and running in exactly the same state.  If you want to re-share the data you will have to do that after you load the class (with set_caller and get_caller functions, for example)

Comment: Note, there are some design patterns that can help keeping all your classes sharing the same data, I find the observer pattern in particular useful for this.

Comment: Finally, if it really makes no sense to serialize your object (for example your object is a mutex recording the current state of your system) then you will have to store that object as a pointer rather than a reference, and pass/create a fresh instance to your class after you have loaded the rest of your class (and omit the non-sensical pointer from the serialization altogether)

Comment: @Tom ,I have tried to serialize the Agent class, save a pointer, load a new pointer, automate the reconstruction by requesting from the simulation API a new instance of Agent to use for reconstructing but it doesn't work, I get undefined references to known static members, but it will not serialize (save) if not static. I have added serialize support to Agent, load & save constructorsto Agent, but it still will not work. I have made extensive changes to the entire project just to make serialization loading work. At this point I am starting to wonder if it is worth serializing. Tom, thank you !

Comment: Whats your error? and what does this mean `ACTION_MODE mode = RAND_SING`;

Comment: ACTION_MODE is an enum, RAND_SING is just one of it's types.
the error is: "undefined reference to 'State::caller' at the line where I do ar <<  guState::caller;

Comment: Is this a linker error?  maybe you have now gone beyond boost.serialization issues

Comment: No it's compiler error. I don't think there is a way to reconstruct and serialize all this without changing the load_construct_data to include an extra parameter from me.

Comment: I don't think there should be a problem - serializing static members should be no problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/666205/static-members-and-boost-serialization, and serializing references and pointers is fine too.

Comment: @Tom, I think I'm going at this the wrong way. I will try to change the Agent into a global singleton, and see from there how I can use the load & save constructors to reconstruct the serialized objects. Thank you for all the help !

Comment: No problem.  It also might be worth building up the simple compilable example piece by piece until it matches what you are wanting to do.  Its always easier breaking something that works than fixing something that doesn't, and then if you get stuck, you know exactly where the problem is and you have a minimal example with which to post your next question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:**

There is a part of the manual that I think we both missed:  The section *non-default constructors* [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html).  To make it work you need to a `save_construct_data` and a `load_construct_data` function.  There is a slight technicallity in terms of where these are friended explored [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4112075/498253).

Also, you said you had this problem when trying to load only, but that you could save fine.  This makes me think that you might have omitted

```
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID(state, "state")
```

This omission might lead to segmentation faults once you get the load compiling (see the export section of the manual)

To make sure I was not mistaken, I made a compiling example, which I add in case its useful.

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>

#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

//base class
struct base
{
  base(double d) : m_d(d) {}
  virtual double run() = 0;
private:

  friend class boost::serialization::access;
  double m_d;
  template <class Archive>
  void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
  {
    ar & m_d;
  }
};

//forward declare the save construct data before friending it 
// (something about friend being in a different namespace)
class derived;
namespace boost { namespace serialization {
template<class Archive>
inline void save_construct_data(Archive & ar, const derived * t, const unsigned int file_version);
}}


//derived class with non-default constructor
struct derived : public base
{
  derived(double a , double b) : 
    base(a+b),
    m_a(a),m_b(b),m_c(a*b) 
  {}
  //some checks
  double get_a() const {return m_a;}
  double get_b() const {return m_b;}
  double get_c() const {return m_c;}

  double run(){return 1.0;}
private:

  friend class boost::serialization::access;
  template<class Archive> 
  friend void boost::serialization::save_construct_data(Archive & ar, const derived * t, const unsigned int file_version);

  template <class Archive>
  void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
  {
    ar & boost::serialization::base_object<base>(*this);
    //only need to return c, a and b already done for constructor
    ar & m_c;
  }
  double m_a, m_b, m_c;
 };

//Save and load the data required for the constructor.
namespace boost { namespace serialization {
  template <class Archive>
    inline void save_construct_data(
                    Archive & ar,const derived* d,const unsigned int file_version
                    )
    {
      // save data required to construct instance
      ar << d->m_a;
      ar << d->m_b;
    }
    template <class Archive>
    inline void load_construct_data(
                        Archive & ar, derived* d,const unsigned int file_version
                        )
    {
      double a,b;
      ar >> a;
      ar >> b;
    // invoke inplace constructor to initialize instance of my_class
      ::new(d) derived(a,b);
    }

  }
}

//register the derived class with boost.
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID(derived, "derived")

int
main  (int ac, char **av)
{
  std::ofstream ofs("filename");
  base* p = new derived(2,3);

  // save data to archive
  {
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
    oa << p;
  }

  // ... some time later restore the class instance to its orginal state
  base* p2;
  {
     std::ifstream ifs("filename");
     boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
     ia >> p2;
  }

  derived* d = static_cast<derived*>(p2);
  std::cout<<"p2 vals are: "<<d->get_a()<<" "<<d->get_b()<<" "<<d->get_c()<<std::endl;

}
```

---

**OLD RESPONSE:**

Not sure I entirely understood your problem (a fuller example would help me) -
The constructor doesn't usually come into it when you serialize an object: you serialize the raw data?

Do you mean that you don't want to serialize all the raw data of the object, but just want to reconstruct it again when you deserialize the object (using the constructor)?  If so then you can do this by seriazing the data that you need for the reconstruction and splitting the save and load operations.

```
struct my_class
{
  my_class(Agent& A, ACTION_MODE const & m)
    : m_state(A,M)
  {}


private: 

  State m_state;

  friend class boost::serialization::access;
  void save(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) const
  {
      // note, version is always the latest when saving
      Agent tmp_A = m_state.get_A();
      ACTION_MODE tmp_m = m_state.get_m();
      ar & tmp_A; 
      ar & tmp_m;
  }
  template<class Archive>
  void load(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
  {
      Agent tmp_A;
      ACTION_MODE tmp_m
      ar & tmp_A; 
      ar & tmp_m;
      m_state = State(tmp_A,tmp_m);
  }
  BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_MEMBER()
}
```

Does that help, or have I missed the point?

Comment: This is what I am trying to do, but when I call "load" I get an error : no matching function for call State::State()
And then it shows the matching functions (Constructors). So I assumed it needed another constructor to do the reconstruction. In my case when reconstructing I need to pass the agent as a parameter. How can I implicitly tell "load" to do that ?