# Boost serializing loading fails with exception thrown

Tags: c++, boost-serialization

I have been trying to make this work for a long time now.

In my project there are 6 classes that are being serialized using the exact tutorial from boost, by implementing the template function serialize.

Those classes are: State, guState, Policy, Action, Param, Vec3D.

When I serialize and save them, it works fine. I get indeed a text file, with various numbers and strings in it.

No complains, no warnings, no exceptions thrown. The only case is that if I try to serialize a pointer member of a class, the hole process becomes a zombie. So I do not try doing so, and saving works.

When however I try loading, I get:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'boost::archive::archive_exception' what():  stream error

Now the interesting part is that I serialize two boost::ptr_vectors, one which consists of State pointers and one which consists of Policy pointers.

The state vector, I have saved and loaded without a problem.
The policy vector, I can save, but when I try loading i get the exception.

Furthermore, after reading the boost tutorials, I was under the impression that In order to load I did not need anything else other than the serialize function.

However when I tried loading, boost serialization would complain for not finding a default constructor such as State(), Policy(), etc (I implement my own constructors in each class ).

After reading [this tutorial here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=398702&rll=1) I implemented a default constructor which does nothing, so that boost-serialization would work. Indeed it did compile, and I got the results mentioned above.

I have tried going down a much complicated road seen in [my old question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734814/boostserialization-reconstruction-loading) where I tried seperating and implementing save_construct_data and load_construct_data, but I found this too instrusive, again I got the exact error as above.

Can someone please help me, explain how the loading works, what is the deal with the default constructors ? Or at least point me to a link that might be helpfull. I have gone through the manuals in boost, and they do not explain much about reconstruction.

Thank you.

Edit (Added a few snippets)

```
class State
{
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version);

  protected:
    std::map<std::string,float> positions;
    float reward;
    std::size_t hash_value;
    bool exists(const Action* A);
    bool operator== (State const& S);
    std::size_t hash();
    void clean_noise();
    State(){}; // NOTE: This is used only by serializer, without it, code won't compile

  public:
    enum position { standing, on_chest, on_back, on_left, on_right, getting_up };
    position current_position;
    Policy *my_policy;
    Vec3D gps;
    boost::ptr_vector<Action> actions;
    State(ACTION_MODE &m);
    ~State();
    bool operator== (State const* S);
    bool operator< (State const* S) const ;
    const float& getR() const;
    bool addAction(Action *A);
    Action* findAction(const Action *A);
    boost::ptr_vector<Action>& getAllActions();
    void printState();
    virtual bool isTerm();
};

template <class Archive>
void State::serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
{
  ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(positions);
  ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(gps);
  ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(current_position);
  ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(reward);
  ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(hash_value);
  ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(actions);
  ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(my_policy);
}
```

Other Classes inheriting from State, have also their serialize functions, using:

```
  ar & boost::serialization::base_object<State>(*this);
```

Class Policy:

```
class Policy
{ 
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version);

    Policy() {}; // NOTE: Again same as with state, used only by serialize load

  protected:

    float QValue;
    State *state;                

  public:

    //! Base class constructor 
    Policy(State *s);
    ...        
};

template <class Archive>
void Policy::serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
{
  ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(action);
  ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(state);
  ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(QValue);
  ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(r);
}
```

As you can see those are the two main classes, Other classes are also serialized because of reconstruction dependencies ( class Action, class Param, etc )

The master Class:

```
template <class S, class P> class Task
{ 
  protected:
    ...
    //! Container of states of type S (template parameter)
    boost::ptr_vector<S> states;
    //! Container of policies of type P (template parameter)
    boost::ptr_vector<P> policies;
    ...

  public:

    Task(Agent &a, ACTION_MODE &m);
    ...
    void save_to_file();
    void load_from_file(std::string filename); 
};

template <class S, class P> 
void Task<S,P>::save_to_file()
{
  std::string output = ramdisk+"serialized";
  char *file = (char*)output.c_str();
  std::ofstream ofs(file);
  assert(ofs.good());  
  boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
  oa << states;
  oa << policies;
  ofs.close();
}

template <class S, class P> 
void Task<S,P>::load_from_file(std::string filename)
{
  char *file = (char*)output.c_str();
  std::cout << file << std::endl;
  std::ifstream ifs(file);
  boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
  ia >> states;
  ia >> policies;
  ifs.close();
}
```

Effectively contains the two boost::ptr_vectors which hold the States and Policies.
States are saved and loaded without a problem.

The problem arises when loading policies. Saving them does not seem to create a problem (but then again I might be wrong).

Having tested save/load without policies, and with, The issue appears to be with policy reconstruction.

Note the default constructors used only by serialization, without which the code will not compile.

EDIT#2: After running application using valgrind and memcheck, it reports that there is a pointer memory leak. However since I am not good at debugging with valgrind I can't really tell where the leak is occuring or if it is relevant to my serialization (I think it is).

Comment: it would be best to paste the code, or code samples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are serializing `states` and `policies` while `Policy` also holds references to the same instances of `State`. You can only serialize classes which don't have such cross-references. Boost *should* throw a pointer-conflict exception when writing to the file. In my tests it dependet on the order of writes if the exception was thrown or not - which is unfortunate because loading fails even if writing succeeded.

A workaround would be to delete the line `oa << states` when saving and loading and fix up the pointers by hand in a post-loading step.

About the constructors: it's mostly something the boost-api needs to do it's template magic. However when using versioning it's important to specify default-values for your member-variables so they are not left uninitialized when loading files with an older version-number.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was indeed the problem there is a triple circular dependency between policies, states and actions.
I will have to save seperately policies and states and then devise a mechanism to link them after loading. I hope this will make it work.
I am not using versioning, so I assume I do not need to specify anything for the default constructors used by boost ?
Thanks again !